# GruntJS: Cannot call method filter of undefined

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I'm new to grunt and tried installing it on a simple project. It worked but when I try to run 'ugilfy' my files I keep getting this error:

```
cannot call method   'filter' of undefined'
```

This is my grunt file (Gruntfile.js), saved in the root of my project:

```
module.exports = function(grunt)


{

grunt.initConfig({

    uglify: 
    { 
        options: 
        {
            mangle: true, 
            compress:true, 
            sourceMap: "dist/app.map", 
            banner: "/*  2014 */" 
        },

        //set of files where the plugin works on, (files which we can affect with our plugins like uglify)
        // culd be dev or production 
        target: 
        {

            //folder name equal to the JS object!!!
            js: "js/app.js", 
            dest: "dist/app.min.js"
        }
    }

});



//load plug-ins
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify'); 


};
```

I seriously have no idea why it is not working. I tried searching on google but I couldn't find any answers.

Comment: Sounds like it doesn't like some of your Javascript. Does `grunt --force` do anything for you?

Comment: Nope still not working :( I get the same warning, but the files are not created:/

Comment: Well it was long shot. You need to check your Javascript. Tools like jslint.com will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`uglify.target` is missing a `src` property.

Change

```
js: "js/app.js",
```

to

```
src: "js/app.js",
```

and it should work properly.

More on specifying sources and destinations are [in the Grunt docs](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks).

Comment: Hey that worked!! :) Does it always has to be called 'src'? I thought it depended on your folder name. 
Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Glad it worked for you! See the [docs on file mappings](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#files) for the different ways you can specify these (since there are several), but in general, if you have a `dest`, you need a `src`.